# Magento discount causing wrong total paid amount (but actually taking correct payment SagePay)

Tags: php, magento, opayo

When checking out in Magento via a discount code we are running into some kind of miscalculation on the order page and the invoice it is generating because of this.

For example:

- Subtotal  £148.50
- Discount  -£22.27
- Tax £21.04
- Grand Total   £126.23
- Total Paid    £122.52
- Total Refunded    £0.00
- Total Due £3.71

Any ideas on how this can be resolved? I would really appreciate any help! I can see SagePay is charging the correct amount (when I log into the test SagePay backend it has charged £126.23) regardless to what is being said here in regards to total paid.

(I have been alerted by one of the users here that this may be a duplicate of a previous question. It is not - it is a different question as this has free shipping - so the double shipping tax issue is not occurring here but actually the opposite!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento charging Shipping Tax Twice (Grand Total Different to Total Paid in Backend)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39117876/magento-charging-shipping-tax-twice-grand-total-different-to-total-paid-in-back)

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of your previous question? I have voted to close.

Comment: It isn't, they are 2 seperate issues. The issue in the previous question revolved around the taxation of shipping. If you look at this one there is no shipping (it is a free shipping order).